# Unity Error error CS0117: 'Screen' does not contain a definition for 'fullscreen'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a game and I was making it's options menu and started scripting the fullscreen toggle. The code I've used for this can be found in a Brackeys tutorial but even after following whatever they did I've ran into this error:
`Assets\Code\OptionsMenuScript.cs(44,16): error CS0117: 'Screen' does not contain a definition for 'fullscreen'`

Most of the code in OptionsMenuScript.cs is useless in this question so I'll narrow it down to the important parts.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SwitchToFullscreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullscreen = isFullscreen;
    }
}
```

Even after looking in Project Settings several times I still haven't found a way to fix this. Am i supposed to define `screen` somewhere in my code? Is `screen` in the Project Settings but under a different name? Can anybody help me with this?

Also, if anyone needs it, I'm using **Unity 2021.3.3f1 (3D Project)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen) {

    Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen; 

}
```

your `Screen.fullScreen` doesn't match with capitalization which I believe is throwing the errors. I tested using the code written above and received no errors in visual studio.